# Canvas arc() doesn't accept variables?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, automatic-ref-counting

Ok, I've got this piece of code, trying to create a fragmented "donut" shape in canvas:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    var endingAngle = (startingAngle + itemLength) % (2 * Math.PI);

    menuItem[i] = new Kinetic.Shape({
        sceneFunc: function (context) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(containerCenter, containerCenter, circleRadius, startingAngle, endingAngle, false);
            context.lineTo(containerCenter + smallCircleRadius * Math.cos(endingAngle), containerCenter + smallCircleRadius * Math.sin(endingAngle));
            context.arc(containerCenter, containerCenter, smallCircleRadius, endingAngle, startingAngle, true);
            context.lineTo(containerCenter + circleRadius * Math.cos(startingAngle), containerCenter + circleRadius * Math.sin(startingAngle));
            context.closePath();

            context.fillStrokeShape(this);
        },
        fill: '#00ff00',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1
    });

    layer.add(menuItem[i]);
    startingAngle = endingAngle;
}
```

startingAngle is set from the outside of this snippet and is basically irrelevant (can have any value), numberOfItems is the number of segments, itemLength the length of each fragment as a percentage of circumference, circleRadius and smallCircleRadius the radii of the outer and inner circle of the donut shape respectively.

Now, when I try to input this as is, it won't draw anything on the canvas, just one line, which seems to be either the left-side line of the first fragment, or the right-side line of the last fragment - although that's irrelevant. If I change the code to constant values instead of the startingAngle and endingAngle, it works, and draws it correctly. What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your startingAngle and endingAngle variables no longer exist when the Kinetic.Shape is trying to draw itself.

Those angle variables disappear from scope when the for-loop ends.

To make the angles available in the sceneFunc you can add the angle properties to the .Shape itself:

```
menuItem[i].startingAngle=startingAngle;
menuItem[i].endingAngle=endingAngle;
```

Then you can retrieve the angles in your sceneFunc:

```
sceneFunc: function(ctx) {
    var startingAngle=this.startingAngle;
    var endingAngle=this.endingAngle
    ...
```

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/465qY/

Comment: Bless you, I would be stuck here forever.